# Existence of gradient perpendicular to a vector field

Tags: vector-analysis

Let $v$ be a divergence-less vector field (in $\mathbb{R}^3$). When can we find a non-constant scalar function $f$ so that $\nabla f$ is perpendicular to $v$?

Comment: Very interesting question. If I got it right, the level surfaces $f^{-1}(c)$ must contain $v$ in the tangent spaces. So basically you ask, when can you split the space to a "smooth foliation" of surfaces invariant with respect to the flow of the vector field. You speak about divergence-free field which makes me think about the velocity of incompressible fluids. I believe that for "laminar flows" it is possible and not for "turbulent flows". If this is complete nonsense, ignore it please :-)

Comment: Excellent response. Your comment very much helped.